# Iphone X Xamarin, se superpone la barra superior

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, iphone

estoy intentando averiguar el modelo de Iphone desde xamarin, ya que con el iphone X mi aplicacion se superpone con la parte de arriba de la pantalla ( en donde aparece la bateria y señal)
Intente con varios medotos como con este [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699251/how-can-i-get-the-current-device-model-on-xamarin-forms) 
pero solo me retorna "Iphone" no me dice si es el 7,8 o X. Y lo necesito para que si es el iphone X ponerle un margen superior mayor

así me queda con el Iphone X, el icono de la batería parece por delante del menú
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi aparece en el Iphone 8 (que esta bien)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien le marque el Use SAfe Area Layout Guide como lei en varios lugares, pero no cambio nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo que tengo para iniciar la vista es:

```
case Device.iOS:
                {
                    BaseLayout = new RelativeLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
                        Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    };
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Logre solucionarlo agregando `SetUseSafeArea(On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>(), true)`

```
case Device.iOS:
    { Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Page.SetUseSafeArea(On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>(), true);
                    BaseLayout = new RelativeLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                    };
                    break;
                }
```